# Laravel: Insert Hash into query

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, encryption, hash

In Codeigniter, I used to use

```
$this->db->where('sha1(id)', $id);
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel?

```
\DB::table('')->where('sha1(id)', $id); ?
\DB::table('')->whereRaw("sha1(id) = '$id'"); ?
```

If I'm about to use Laravel Hash facade, how can I achieve it?

```
\DB::table('')->where('\Hash::make(id)', $id);
```

My main goal is to searching into table where hash(id -> from table) = $id -> (method param)

Comment: Can you show how you inserted that id? what method are you using to store that `id`?

Comment: Whic one the id that you mean? is it from the table, or id from the param?
If from the table, I am inserting it in a normal way, I use Auto Increment form the dm machine instead.
But the $id param, I am using two function at my controller, first I'm hashing it, then return it for the ajax response, then from javascript, I redirecting into route detail/hashed_id

Answer (score 1):

`sha1()` is a MySQL function that generate `sha1` string

if you want to use from MySQL then use

```
\DB::table('')->where(\DB::raw('sha1(id)'), $id);
```

But I recommended using Laravel facade like this

```
\DB::table('')->where('id', \Hash::make($id));
```

Comment: The laravel facade is the other way around man, because my id us just a normal integer, so I want to hashing it and compare it with my param id, which is already hashed

Comment: which MySQL version are you using? may sha1 function has come in MySQL 8.0.0 version. please check id.

Comment: SEE how to use the function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1

Comment: Ouw I'm sorry, I don't say it clearly, for the DB, I'm using SQR Server. But the sha1 func, just works using codeigniter.

Comment: I never use SQR. I recommend using Laravel Hash to store, retrieve search if SQR does not have encryption function.

Comment: Using `Hash::make` inside the query is wrong. `Hash::make` generates a randomized hash string on each run (for a constant string).

Answer (score 0):

You got close!

Try:

```
\DB::table('')->where(\DB::raw('sha1(id)'), $id);
```

Comment: I got this error:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'sha1' is not a recognized built-in function name. (SQL: select top 1 * from [ediscount_header] where sha1(id) = **

Comment: Yea, so sha1 is not a database function. Are you trying to use the PHP built in to hash the value?

Comment: Yes man... I know that that is not a database function but, I don't know, it's just work in codeigniter man....like, my code up there